# Gradle: java.lang.StackOverflowError when compiling a spark-scala program

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, gradle

I ran into this problem and there was no error message.

Problem finding:
I suspected this problem had something to do with a schema I tried to create for my dataframe, ie: a StructType variable with a lot of StructField's. After several attempts at shortening the number of StructField that StructType has, **I found out the problem is indeed resulted from having a large number of StructField**, and it seemed to me that the maximum number of StructField it could hold varies every time I ran gradle build.

My attempts to solve the problem:
I did some search but could only find solutions to solve stackoverflow error that weren't caused by having a large StructType. I tried to increase the stack memory limit using jvm options, and that did not work either and broke my gradle.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, in case anyone else is running into this problem, you can separate StructType into smaller groups and it would work.